# How can I use sscanf with white space?

Tags: c, string, split, scanf, whitespace

I am trying to split a string into some pieces, but it is not doing this properly. Here is my code.

```
int main(void){
    char point[2][2];
    char *try="Distance P1 P2 // Prints the distance between P1 and P2.";
    sscanf(try,"Distance %s %s",point[0], point[1]);
    printf("point[0]:%s point[1]: %s\n",point[0],point[1] ); 

}
```

Expecting this

```
point[0]:P1 point[1]:P2
```

OUTPUT

```
point[0]:P1P2 point[1]: P2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char point[2][3];
    char *try="Distance P1 P2 " ; // Prints the distance between P1 and P2;
    sscanf(try,"Distance %s %s",point[0], point[1]);
    printf("point[0]:%s point[1]: %s\n",point[0],point[1] );
    return 0;
}
```